# Why $||y|| = \max_{||b|| \leq 1} y^tb$?

Tags: normed-spaces

I read [Application of Legendre transformation in computer vision](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/research/technicalreports/2011/DTR11-7.pdf) 
And at part 5.1 I found a strange equality

$||y|| = \max_{||b|| \leq 1} y^tb$

Can anyone provide me intuition why this equality is correct? And how obtain it from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

PS Sorry for my English and math skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states:

1. $|y^t b| \le \Vert y \Vert \Vert b \Vert$ for all vectors $y,b$
2. That you have equality in previous inequality if and only if the vectors are collinear.
   Are you able to conclude with this?

Comment: It's funny: i miss fact that if we divide inequality by ||b|| inequality stay correct. Thank you. I think that i understand this